# Not an usable net address error when integrating ML 9 with Connector-for-Hadoop2-2.2.3?

Tags: hadoop, marklogic, marklogic-9

Following this  [ML documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mapreduce/quickstart) I am running sample marklogic-hello-world.xml by using the configuration that was present in the documentation. My localhost name is `ubuntu.localdomain` . When i am giving the same in my configuration file it is throwing error like this

```
    18/01/04 22:39:54 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
18/01/04 22:39:54 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
18/01/04 22:39:54 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
18/01/04 22:39:54 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
18/01/04 22:39:54 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
18/01/04 22:39:54 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
18/01/04 22:40:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
18/01/04 22:40:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
18/01/04 22:40:05 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local196795803_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Default provider - Not a usable net address: ubuntu.localdomain:8000
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Default provider - Not a usable net address: ubuntu.localdomain:8000
    at com.marklogic.xcc.ContentSourceFactory.defaultConnectionProvider(ContentSourceFactory.java:453)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.ContentSourceFactory.newContentSource(ContentSourceFactory.java:264)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.ContentSourceFactory.newContentSource(ContentSourceFactory.java:321)
    at com.marklogic.mapreduce.utilities.InternalUtilities.getInputContentSource(InternalUtilities.java:127)
    at com.marklogic.mapreduce.MarkLogicRecordReader.init(MarkLogicRecordReader.java:348)
    at com.marklogic.mapreduce.MarkLogicRecordReader.initialize(MarkLogicRecordReader.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
18/01/04 22:40:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local196795803_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
18/01/04 22:40:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

My configuration file is like this

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.marklogic.input.username</name>
        <value>admin</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.marklogic.input.password</name>
        <value>admin</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.marklogic.input.host</name>
        <value>ubuntu.localdomain</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.marklogic.input.port</name>
        <value>8000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.marklogic.input.mode</name>
        <value>basic</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.marklogic.input.valueclass</name>
        <value>com.marklogic.mapreduce.DatabaseDocument</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.marklogic.output.username</name>
        <value>admin</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.marklogic.output.password</name>
        <value>admin</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.marklogic.output.host</name>
        <value>ubuntu.localdomain</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.marklogic.output.port</name>
        <value>8000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.marklogic.output.content.type</name>
        <value>TEXT</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I had tried by giving various names for this `mapreduce.marklogic.input.host` i tried with `127.0.0.1` & `localhost` but by default it is taking `ubuntu.localdomain`.

I dont know why it is taking default one rather than taking the one which i had specified in configuration.xml file (i.e.`127.0.0.1` etc) .

I had used the below command to run this

```
hadoop jar \
  $CONNECTOR_HOME/lib/marklogic-mapreduce-examples-version.jar \
  com.marklogic.mapreduce.examples.HelloWorld -libjars $LIBJARS \
  -conf marklogic-hello-world.xml
```

As specifed in the document.

How can i overcome this ? Any help is appreciated ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by changing the localhost name in Marklogic configuration page from `ubuntu.localdomain` to `localhost` then the above configuration worked well. But Still cant able to find why it is not picking `hostname` from configuration files rather then going to ML .

Comment: The name of a server is not always the same as how it is known on a network. Are you sure `ubuntu.localdomain` is also the name how your server can be access over network? Check your local DHCP and/or DNS server how it is logged there to verify. Localhost will just always work if things are running on the same server, so less complicated.